# ActiveJob does not execute the job asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am trying to implement an API endpoint that would queue a request and return immediately.

I am using the gem https://rubygems.org/gems/activejob/versions/5.2.0 (I am on an old version for historical reasons).

I have defined a job that looks something like:

```
class Service::ExportBooks::Job < ActiveJob::Base

  def perform
    ## ... Do the job
  rescue StandardError
    binding.pry
    raise
  end

end
```

In the controller, I am calling:

```
Service::ExportBooks::Job.perform_later
```

The job gets called synchronously and the controller gets even any errors raised by the job.

I've also tried other options such as:

```
job = Service::ExportBooks::Job.new
job.enqueue(wait: 5.seconds)
```

but it does the same, the job is not enqueued, is immediately executed.

UPDATE:
It looks like the method Resque.inline? returns true and so the execution is inline and not async. How can I make sure that it's async? I tried to set Resque.inline = false manually and the job was queued but it wasn't executed...

I have started a worker using the command:

```
 QUEUE=* PIDFILE=./tmp/resque.pid bundle exec rake environment resque:work
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to do here.

1. Make sure `Resque.inline = false`.
2. Start up the resque workers in another process. [See here](https://github.com/resque/resque#running-workers).

This will get the job enqueued and run on the worker process.

Comment: Where should I set Resque.inline = false? At startup ?
I have a resque worker running. I started it as mentioned in my update above.
By the way, in my previous "update" I said that I tried with Resque.inline = true, but I meant the opposite. When it's true, it is executed inline, when I set it to false, it wan't executed at all.

Comment: I believe `false` it the default setting. You may not need to set it at all.